# How can I enlarge a table row when hovering over it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html-table

I am trying to build a jQuery plugin that resembles the enlarge image on mouse over - but on table rows:

```
var trEnlargedCssMap = 
{
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '50px',
    top: '50px',
    'font-size': '14px'
}

$('table tr').hover(
    function()
    {
        $(this).clone().css(trEnlargedCssMap).show();
    },
    function()
    {
        $(this).hide();
    })
```

It not close to working, any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to append it to the DOM/table (whereever you want). I appended it to the existing table. You also should `.remove()` any of the cloned elements when your hover out as opposed to hiding them. Please change the attributes as needed for your application.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/uQEUz/1/)

```
var trEnlargedCssMap = {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '50px',
    top: '50px',
    'font-size': '20px'
}

    $('table tr').hover(

function() {
    $(this).closest("table").append(
    $(this).clone().addClass("cloned-element").css(trEnlargedCssMap).show())
}, function() {
    $(this).closest("table").find(".cloned-element").remove();
})​



<table>
<tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Row 3</td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

Comment: I would not use $("table").append(...) if there is more than one table in the page. It will append to all the tables. using appendTo to the current table might be better.

Comment: Agreed 100%! I have updated the answer to reference the specific table that is being hovered. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: my td's are too short in case they are empty in the original row. I tried to set the td `min-width: 20px;` in the original row and hope it gets translated to the cloned row. but no luck.. any suggestions?

Comment: `min-width` works for me. Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/uQEUz/2/). Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `append()` it somewhere. Here you just clone it and do nothing...

So `$(this).clone().css(trEnlargedCssMap).appendTo('#myZoomedRow');`

Answer (score 0):

You have to append that clone element to the DOM, and hide (or remove it to prevent conflict) the "new" element insted of the actual row from you cloned.

```
var trEnlargedCssMap = {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '50px',
        top: '50px',
        'font-size': '14px'
    }
$('table tr').hover(
                    function(){
                        $(this).clone().css(trEnlargedCssMap).appendTo("#newRow").show();
                    },
                    function(){
                         $("#newRow").hide();
                    }
                    )
```