# How can I enlarge a table row when hovering over it? - Variation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

****clarification**
I made this [Fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/sggPv/10/) to help clarify the situation.

The script works for both tables at first, but then when you hit the slider and load a new table into the div, it stops working.

I can't use a magnifier because the text is very small and I barely want to see the text at all.  I just want the hover property to show the value of the td.

****original question**

This is in reference to this [previous question: 'how-can-i-enlarge-a-table-row-when-hovering-over-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072577/how-can-i-enlarge-a-table-row-when-hovering-over-it')

I have several tables in my page and I want specific tables to display values and some not to.  The tables are not direct html.  The tables appear in `<div>` tags and are loaded with a slider.

Here is the code I use to get a table in the html itself to load:

#### CSS

```
td.cloned-element {
  min-width:50px;
}
```

#### Code

```
var tdEnlargedCssMap = {
  position: 'fixed',
  left: '800px',
  top: '250px',
  'font-size': '30px'
}

$('td').hover(

function() {
   $(this).closest("table").append(
   $(this).clone().addClass("cloned-element").css(tdEnlargedCssMap).show())
   }, function() {
     $(this).closest("table").find(".cloned-element").remove();
})
```

I tried changing the CSS to this:

```
#tab td.cloned-element {
    min-width:50px;   
}
```

but it still only works on the `"general"` table elements in the page and not in the table loaded in the

```
<div id="tab">
```

The problem is it can't "find" the td elements in the div.  I'm not sure how to get it to do this.  Can I get an assist please?

Comment: Did you try just hitting CTRL and + to make the table larger ?

Comment: What order are you running your JS in? The slider has to load before your custom script. And I think `#tab td .cloned-element` should be the correct selector (I'm not sure how CSS handles whitespace, but this is a format I'm familiar with and know works). FYI, there are some JQuery plugins that do a "zoom" effect over images, and these might be a good place to look for comparison.

Comment: Just looking at your other question - so you're already aware of the existing image plugins :)

Comment: Why can't you just use css? `tr:hover { font-size: 20px; }` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uQEUz/6/))

Comment: Alternatively, you could just the AnythingZoomer plugin... [this demo](http://css-tricks.github.io/AnythingZoomer/) shows how you can use two tables (small & large) to have a zoom effect.

Comment: Here is another js that works fairly well - if it works with `li` it ought to work with `td`. http://iscrolljs.com/

Comment: @Mottie I would assume that straight CSS won't work because it needs to be adaptable to whatever kind of content is in the table (text, images, iframes). Also, judging by the code we have, it appears the desired effect is a separate "zoom window" like we see on eBay and Newegg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this works on any `trs` on the page initially (when the javascript runs), but not on tables added later? That's what I understood from your comments: "The tables appear in tags and are loaded with a slider" and "it still only works on the "general" table elements in the page and not in the table loaded in the `<div id="tab">`"

If so, it's probably because the listener is only attached to elements on the page when it loads. Instead, attach the listener to the body, or preferably a wrapper element that includes all your tables.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uQEUz/9/

```
$('body')
    .on('mouseenter', 'table tr', function() {
        $(this).closest("table").append(
        $(this).clone().addClass("cloned-element").css(trEnlargedCssMap).show());
    })
    .on('mouseleave', 'table tr', function(){
        $(this).closest("table").find(".cloned-element").remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the example fiddle in the answer to your old question, so [it is available here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaycenornin/uQEUz/8/).

The code is below, and as you can see, the clone script does find the appended table. I suspect your issue is with your script load order. As long as your slider runs, and finishes running, first, then your script will detect the table. In most cases, Javascript will run sequentially, not in parallel, so whichever script appears first in your html will be the first script to run.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Row 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p> Load Table
<div id="myTab"></div>
</p>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
// consider this your slider, it dynamically adds a table to the page.
$("#myTab").append("<table><tr><td>Row1</td><td>Row1</td><td>Row1</td></tr><tr><td>Row2</td><td>Row2</td><td>Row2</td></tr><tr><td>Row3</td><td>Row3</td><td>Row3</td></tr></table>");

var trEnlargedCssMap = {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '50px',
    top: '50px',
    'font-size': '20px'
};

$('table tr').hover(

function() {
    $(this).closest("table").append(
    $(this).clone().addClass("cloned-element").css(trEnlargedCssMap).show());
}, function() {
    $(this).closest("table").find(".cloned-element").remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: if you look at the fiddle I posted, it doesn't work with my application.  It works INITIALLY, but then stops working when another table is loaded in the div.

Comment: @Crimpy I wrote my answer before you had the fiddle. I've been playing :) I see you've already accepted an answer, but an alternative solution (that I've tested on your fiddle) would be to put your `$('td').hover` etc. into a function `function thover()` and then call that function inside `function instrumentV2Slider` where you also call `updateTable()` etc. You could also call the function in `$(document).load()` to have it fire when the page loads the first time. I've tested and this works. The reason why is as cjspurg describes - the listener doesn't fire when the page changes.

Comment: Can you share with me the fiddle you've made so I can see the alternative method? I'm always looking for different ways of doing things... Thanks!